# python comprehension with multiple 'for' clauses and single 'if'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine a discrete x,y,z space :  I am trying to create an iterator which will return all points which lie within a sphere of some radial distance from a point.

My  approach was to first look at all points within a larger cube which is guaranteed to contain all the points needed and then cull or skip points which are too far away.

My first attempt was:

```
x,y,z=(0,0,1)
dist=2
#this doesn't work
it_0=((x+xp,y+yp,z+zp) for xp in range(-dist,dist+1) for yp in range(-dist,dist+1) for zp in range(-dist,dist+1) if ( ((x-xp)**2+(y-yp)**2+(z-zp)**2) <= dist**2+sys.float_info.epsilon ) )
```

a simple

```
for d,e,f in it_0:
    #print(d,e,f)
    print( ((x-d)**2+(y-e)**2+(z-f)**2) <= dist**2+sys.float_info.epsilon,  d,e,f)
```

verifies that it_0 does not produce correct results.  I believe it is applying the conditional only to the third (ie: z) 'for' clause

The following works:

```
it_1=((x+xp,y+yp,z+zp) for xp in range(-dist,dist+1) for yp in range(-dist,dist+1) for zp in range(-dist,dist+1))
it_2=filter( lambda p: ((x-p[0])**2+(y-p[1])**2+(z-p[2])**2) <= dist**2+sys.float_info.epsilon, it_1)
```

It collects all the points, then filter those which don't fit the conditional.

I was hoping there might be a way to correct the first attempted implementation, or make these expressions more readable or compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you replace the triply-nested `for` loop with `itertools.product()`, like so:

```
import itertools as it
it_1 = it.product(range(-dist, dist+1), repeat=3)
```

If you are using Python 2.x, you should use `xrange()` here instead of `range()`.

Next, instead of using `filter()` you could just use a generator expression:

```
it_2=(x, y, z for x, y, z in it_1 if ((x-p[0])**2+(y-p[1])**2+(z-p[2])**2) <= dist**2+sys.float_info.epsilon)
```

This would avoid some overhead in Python 2.x (since `filter()` builds a list), but for Python 3.x would be about the same; and even in Python 2.x you could use `itertools.ifilter()`.

But for readability, I would package the whole thing up into a generator, like so:

```
import itertools as it
import sys

def sphere_points(radius=0, origin=(0,0,0), epsilon=sys.float_info.epsilon):
    x0, y0, z0 = origin
    limit = radius**2 + epsilon
    for x, y, z in it.product(range(-radius, radius+1), repeat=3):
        if (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) <= limit:
            yield (x+x0, y+y0, z+z0)
```

I just changed the code from your original code.  Each range for x, y, and z is adjusted to center around the origin point.  When I test this code with a radius of 0, I correctly get back a single point, the origin point.

Note that I provided arguments to the function letting you specify radius, origin point, and even the value to use for epsilon, with defaults for each.  I also unpacked the origin point tuple into explicit variables; I'm not sure if Python would optimize away the indexing operation or not, but this way we know there won't be any indexing going on inside the loop.  (I think the Python compiler would probably hoist the `limit` calculation out of the loop, but I actually prefer it on its own line as shown here, for readability.)

I think the above is about as fast as you can write it in native Python, and I think it is a big improvement in readability.

P.S. This code would probably run a lot faster if it was redone using Cython.

http://cython.org/

EDIT: Code simplified as suggested by @eryksun in comments.

Comment: Thanks, and I'll consider Cython once I'm farther along and have a better picture of where my program spends most of its time.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you for pointing that out.  I answered this in a hurry before leaving the house today, and I missed the simpler way to code it.

Comment: I'd think it's a numpy job if performance is an actual concern; my first thought was that it's an algorithm and language exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You've confused the meanings of xp, yp, zp in your generator expression:

```
it_0=((x+xp,y+yp,z+zp) for xp in range(-dist,dist+1) for yp in range(-dist,dist+1) for zp in range(-dist,dist+1) if ( ((x-xp)**2+(y-yp)**2+(z-zp)**2) <= dist**2+sys.float_info.epsilon ) )
```

xp, yp, and zp are already the distances from the center of the sphere along the various axes. Thus you should not be taking the difference from x, y, z again. The expression should be:

```
it_0=((x+xp,y+yp,z+zp) for xp in range(-dist,dist+1) for yp in range(-dist,dist+1) for zp in range(-dist,dist+1) if ( (xp**2+yp**2+zp**2) <= dist**2+sys.float_info.epsilon ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `epsilon` is a bit off. The documentation for sys.float_info describes it as the difference between 1 and the next representable float, so it is too small to make a difference on 2, let alone 2**2.

Secondly, all your points are measured from x,y,z in the filter/if then offset by it in the result expression `(x+xp,y+yp,z+zp)`. You'll get a rather off-centre sphere that way, so try `(xp,yp,zp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the logic errors.  I'll address readability.  Also note with the data given, there is no floating point involved, so an epsilon is not needed.

```
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

x,y,z = 0,0,1
r = 2

def points_in_circle(radius):
    '''return a generator of all integral points in circle of given radius.'''
    return ((x,y,z)
            for x,y,z in product(range(-dist,dist+1),repeat=3)
            if x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= radius**2)

# List integral points of radius r around point (x,y,z).
pprint([(x+xp,y+yp,z+zp) for xp,yp,zp in points_in_circle(r)])
```

#### Output

```
[(-2, 0, 1),
 (-1, -1, 0),
 (-1, -1, 1),
 (-1, -1, 2),
 (-1, 0, 0),
 (-1, 0, 1),
 (-1, 0, 2),
 (-1, 1, 0),
 (-1, 1, 1),
 (-1, 1, 2),
 (0, -2, 1),
 (0, -1, 0),
 (0, -1, 1),
 (0, -1, 2),
 (0, 0, -1),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 3),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 1),
 (1, -1, 0),
 (1, -1, 1),
 (1, -1, 2),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (2, 0, 1)]
```